SSH Connection: Ubuntu Mate 22.04 64 bit on Raspberry Pi 4B (no screen)
I have a Raspberry Pi 4B 64 bit. I have flashed an Ubuntu Mate 22.04 Desktop 64 bit onto a 64GB SD card with Win32DiskImager (the reason I don't use official Raspberry Pi Imager/Etcher is because the imager cannot validate my SD card for some reason; I have tried another SD card 32GB but still failed).
I wanted to access the RPi 4B with SSH. I have already connected it to the same network with router. I cannot find its IP in my network with Angry IP Scanner or Advanced IP Scanner.
I have tried a method in many older tutorials teaching me to create a "SSH" file and "wpa-supplicant.conf" in the boot partition with the correct Wi-Fi credentials. It didn't work. Also some tutorials also stated this method is no longer relevant in newer versions.
Any advice on what I can do? Highly appreciated!
ps. Ultimately I am trying access the Pi to install LCD package.
FYI: The Pi was actually working fine with Ubuntu Mate Desktop 32-bit with the image provided by the seller with the LCD package and all SSH setting done for me. It's just that I can't seem to replicate the same for 64-bit version if I do everything manually just by myself.

Have you connected video directly to the pi to check if it is actually booting?

@user10489 I have connected the LCD screen to the Pi, it was glowing white screen.

Your router should have the Pi listed, if not then it is not getting an IP address which could be because it is not recognizing the onboard nic/wifi.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This answer would be my second guess as to what is wrong, and the suggested approach (asking the wifi router) is a good.  Could still be expanded.

Yes, it's true that the IP scanner couldn't find the IP, this is why I want to know how to set up the SSH headlessly in my case. It was able to recognize it previously when the Pi was using the image provided by the seller (Ubuntu Mate 32-bit) which the LCD package and all SSH setting done for me.
